# found his apartment broken into and his antique vase missing

Tags: complements, coordination, participial-adjectives

Do native speakers find the following sentence natural?

> Joe found his apartment broken into and his antique vase missing.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct, but it's a bit terse. A native English speaker would use more words, for example:

> Joe found that his apartment had been broken into and his antique vase was missing.

Comment: Could you explain why it's correct, please?

Comment: @Apollyon could you explain what you think might **not** be correct?

Comment: What are the grammatical roles of "broken into" and "missing" in my original example?